# Save current state of scene and load it

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

How do i save current scene state and load it later?

I'm making a game where you are building a bridge and then press start to run over it with a car and if you fail you have a restart button that reloads the scene from origin state(without anything built on it). However, i want the player to be able to press an "Edit" button that will go back to the state right before you pressed "start" so you can keep building on your bridge without having to rebuild the whole bridge over and over again. So, how do i do this?

Comment: Code it yourself. You can save all the objects positions before player presses start (for example in a map). Then when you need to restore, read all these positions and set them to corresponding objects. Alternatively, you can have two copies of the world. One for editing (you don't run your game on it), and one for simulation (where game runs) when players presses start, you can create a mirror copy of editing world, and run your game on this copy. To restore, just move camera back to editing world, and destroy game world

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to code it yourself, you can use the PlayerPrefs of Unity. If you don't know how to use it look at the documentation (https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/PlayerPrefs.html) or you can also find tuto on Youtube, even some examples.